# Upload more than 30 Files in Php

Tags: php, file-upload

I am new to php and I am trying to upload more than 30 files in `file upload` (php).
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set `max_file_uploads` in your php.ini file to a higher number.

Answer (score 2):

There is a php.ini setting called [`max_file_uploads`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.max-file-uploads). Change it to 30 and your problem should be solved.

Having said that, there are other settings you might want to change: [`upload_max_filesize`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize) and [`post_max_size`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size). Together, they control the maximum individual and combined file size.